# Knockout JS - parse / format value (extenders?)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need a simple convert value between model and view. I have a number which I want in template display exposed via thousands but in model I need work with it.

For example (extender for explode digit to "123 123 123" and back):

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
var result = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return target().toFixed(precision).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
    },
    write: function(value) {
        return parseFloat(target().toString().replace(" ", ""));
    }
});

result.raw = target;
return result;
```

};

My bad model, I must parse exploded number here:

```
var Model = function(number) {
     this.multiply = ko.observable(number).extend({ numeric : 0 });
     this.result = ko.computed(function(){  
         var multiply = this.multiply();
         // HERE IS A PROBLEM - not converted back to the number
         return multiply * 1234;
     }, this).extend({ numeric : 0 });
};

ko.applyBindings(new Model(123123123));
```

In my example is not called **write** for convert exploded number back to the float. I tried it a lot of but it still doesn't work (turn over read and write etc).

Thank you for help!

Comment: It's mainly language issues (I think), but your question is very hard to understand imho. Could you try to edit and clarify? Perhaps a fiddle as well as some more details on the expected output would help?

Comment: Ok, so I create it in http://jsfiddle.net/sFyx6/1/ .. I created working example, but I want move parsing of number from model to the extenders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd gain more from your relationship if you stored your actual number separate from the string representation. If you run the calc on a third computed value, then both forms of the original number are available. This is the best way to simulate the in/out feature you were hoping for in the extension. The extensions don't really work like that.

http://jsfiddle.net/sFyx6/7/

```
    // store the actual number here for manipulating later
    self.number = ko.observable(number);
    // This value is for display
    self.spreadNum = ko.observable(number).extend({ numeric : 0 }); 
    // Keep another computed value for editing
    self.calcNum = ko.computed({ 
        read: function() {
            return self.number() * 234.56;
        }} );
```

Comment: How flattering... ;)
Glad it helped.